# how to get range the html > td.a > Javascript link in python

Tags: javascript, python, range, href

i web t to create a the small python tool, For selenium web table content javascript link,But i'm not quite sure how to write?

https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/index.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-03-06&venue=ST&raceno=8

#horseTable > tbody > tr > td > a

````
    for race in range(1, race_count+1):

        driver.get( '.com' )
        
        **
tbody = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id="horseTable"] tbody')[0]
        trs = tbody.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr')
        tds = trs.find_elements_by_css_selector('#horseTable > tbody > tr > td > a')
**
        *
        tr_header = trs[0]
        trs_body = trs[ 0 : -1 ]
        tds_link = tds[0 : -1]
        *

        for td in tds:
            row_header.append(td.text.strip() )
           
        data = []
        for tr in trs_body:
            row = []
            tds = tr.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')
            for td in tds:
                row.append( td.text.strip() )
            data.append( row )
            
        now = str(datetime.datetime.now())[0:19]
        *
        link = []
        link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('#horseTable > tbody > tr > td > a')
        link.click()
        *
            ```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. If you get error then show it in question (not in comment) as text.

Comment: maybe click on link and get URL from new page - `driver.url` - and later go back

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

Comment: Hello Furas, Thank you help me check then and comment me,  I want to use the python program to download house data, But this page uses javascript for create house link, How to write the program loop for download house list?